# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) although all the brackets are present in the code

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the error PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)" on line 97. I already checked the brackets for many times and seems like all the brackets are fine. Can anyone recheck my code and show me if I've missed anything in the code?

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://www.cssscript.com/wp-includes/css/sticky.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>MS BPR organization chart</title>
    <?php


    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

    error_reporting(E_ALL);


    include 'DBcon.php';

    ?>
</head>

<body>
<div id="css-script-menu">
    <div class="css-script-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssscript.com/responsive-hierarchical-organization-chart-pure-css/">Download</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cssscript.com/">Back To CSS Script</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="css-script-ads">
            <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
                /* CSSScript Demo Page */
                google_ad_slot = "3025259193";
                google_ad_width = 728;
                google_ad_height = 90;
                //-->
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="css-script-clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <h1>MS BPR Organization Chart</h1>
        <ol class="organizational-chart">
            <li>
                <?php

                //Print all items from database.
                $query = "SELECT * FROM [MSBPR].[dbo].[MSTeam] ORDER BY Position,MSGroup,Name";
                $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die("Couldn't execut query");


                while ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){


                $MSGroup = $data['MSGroup'];
                $NAME = $data['Name'];
                $Phone = $data['Phone'];
                $Email = $data['Email'];
                $Image = $data['Image'];
                if ($MSGroup == 'HOD'){
                ?>
                <div>
                    <h1>HOD</h1>

                </div>


                <ol>
                    <?php

                    } else if ($MSGroup == 'Managerial') {
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <div>
                                <h2>Managerial</h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </ol>
                <ol>

                    <li>
                        <div><h2>LN</h2></div>

                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <?php else if ($MSGroup=='LN'){ ?>
                                <div><h2><?php echo "$Name"; ?></h2></div>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                        <?php
                        }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><h2>Lotus Note</h2></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><h2>Hardware</h2></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><h2>Subsystem</h2></div>
                    </li>
                </ol>
                
            </li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-46156385-1', 'cssscript.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me recheck on this error

Comment: Check where you closed the block of the previous `else if ($MSGroup=='Managerial')`. That happens somewhere in between the two, and then you have arbitrary HTML code before the next else. The else has to immediately follow the if block, you can not insert other arbitrary content between the two at will.

Comment: @CBroe I already checked the closing brackets and that's the way i want the <li> to loop. Do you have other solutions to allow that to happen?

Comment: There's stuff happening between the closing bracket at line line 86, and the next if statement. What did you expect PHP to do with all that HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include the html in between line no 86 and 97. It is an syntax error

I have commented the html in below code. Please try it will work.
If you want the commented html on every loop, Just add it in all the if, else conditions

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://www.cssscript.com/wp-includes/css/sticky.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>MS BPR organization chart</title>
    <?php
    
    
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
     
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    
    
    include 'DBcon.php';
    
    ?>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="css-script-menu">
      <div class="css-script-center">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.cssscript.com/responsive-hierarchical-organization-chart-pure-css/">Download</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.cssscript.com/">Back To CSS Script</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="css-script-ads">
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
    /* CSSScript Demo Page */
    google_ad_slot = "3025259193";
    google_ad_width = 728;
    google_ad_height = 90;
    //-->
    </script>
          <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script></div>
        <div class="css-script-clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
    <h1>MS BPR Organization Chart</h1>
            <ol class="organizational-chart">
                <li>
     <?php
    
      //Print all items from database.
      $query = "SELECT * FROM [MSBPR].[dbo].[MSTeam] ORDER BY Position,MSGroup,Name";
         $result=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die("Couldn't execut query");
    
    
    while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    
    
        $MSGroup = $data['MSGroup'];
        $NAME = $data['Name'];
        $Phone = $data['Phone'];
        $Email = $data['Email'];
        $Image=$data['Image'];
    if($MSGroup=='HOD'){
        ?>
                   <div>
                        <h1>HOD</h1>
    
                    </div>
    
                  
                    <ol>
    <?php
    
    }else if ($MSGroup=='Managerial'){
    ?>
                        <li>
                            <div>
                                <h2>Managerial</h2>
                            </div>
    </li>
    <?php
    }else if ($MSGroup=='LN'){
     ?>
    <div> <h2><?php echo"$Name";?></h2></div>
    </li>
    </ol>
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div> <h2>Lotus Note</h2></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div> <h2>Hardware</h2></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div> <h2>Subsystem</h2></div>
    </li>
    </ol>
    
                                    
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
    
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    
      ga('create', 'UA-46156385-1', 'cssscript.com');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It shows the same error and no difference

Comment: We should not seperate  } and else. please check the updated answer